# Find a delta for limits or continuity of function of two variables

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $$f(x,y) = \Bigg\{ \frac{2x^4-5x^3y^2+y^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2} when (x,y) \neq (0,0) $$ and $$f(0,0) = 0 $$.

Find a $\delta >0$ such that $ | f(x,y) - f(0,0| < 0.01 $ whenever $\sqrt{x^2+y^2} < \delta$.

The above question is given as part of calculus course college.

I know that this is some thing related to limits or continuity of functions of two variables. Beyond that, I don't have any clue on how to approach.

Please help me to solve the above problem.

Comment: Are you sure the numerator doesn't begin with $\;2x^{\color{red}5}$?

Comment: @Bernard, I  will recheck with my course instructor and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: let $x = at, y = bt$, where $a^2 + b^2 = 1$ and $t \ge 0$. With the correction Bernard suggests, all you will need then is to find an upper bound on an expression in $a$ and $b$.

And it also should explain why Bernard made the suggestion (the function as defined is not continuous at $(0,0)$).